# How to scale a div while keeping top in same place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an iframe (lets call it a div to simplify things), that has a `transform: scale` property that I'm calling with javascript.This scales the div, but however, it also shifts the div upwards. I would like the top to stay in the same place.

Background info (from answers suggestions): I want to create something that looks like google docs. I have created an iframe that will transform when an input box value is change (like google docs). I want the top to remain in the same place (like google docs).

1) I have tried in javascript to implement `document.getElementById("textareathingy").style.transform = "translateY(1000px)";                     document.getElementById("textareathingy").style.transform = "scale(" + percentage + ")";` I tried to put the `translate` both before and after the `scale`, but both methods do not work, and the div continues to go upwards when I put `translate` first, and the div does not zoom in when I put `scale` first.

2) I have tried to put `position: absolute;` to counteract it going up, but that doesn't help either, and it gets rid of my scrolling feature on the div. So in answers please don't use position: absolute.

3) I have tried using the `zoom` feature, but that doesn't zoom in on the contents of the div, so that also doesn't work.

For some reason, there is no error messages in any of my attempts.

Here is also my css for the div:

```
#textareathingy{
  width: 820px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 1000px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Here are two pictures from google docs that represents what I want. [image: Zoomed in at 100%]
[image: Zoomed in at 200%]

Notice how they both have the same "top" position, but it is zoomed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`transform-origin` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to set the point in the element that the transform should originate from. Set this to `top` so that the scale extends downward from the top point.

```css
img { border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS Transforms</title>

  <style>
    img {
      /* Single Transformations: */
      transform-origin: top;
    }
    
    /* Triggering a transformation: */
    img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <img class="car" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
</body>
</html>
```

To trigger this from JavaScript, just access the `transformOrigin` property as you would any other:

```js
let img = document.querySelector("img");
img.style.transformOrigin = "top"; // Set the origin

img.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  this.classList.add("scale");
});

img.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  this.classList.remove("scale");
});
```

```css
.scale {
  transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
}

img { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS Transforms</title>

  <style>
    img {
      /* Single Transformations: */
      transform-origin: center;
    }
    
    /* Triggering a transformation: */
    img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <img class="car" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
</body>
</html>
```